# Alexa Voice Service: Login with Amazon android

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

While trying to implement login with Amazon for Alexa Voice Service, When the user clicks on the imageButton Browser View is being displayed and it gets closed automatically.

The Following were displayed in the log cat.

```
12-13 18:25:09.352: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(3337): APIKey:<obscured>
12-13 18:25:09.352: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): verifySignature for packageName=com.example.helloworldsample
12-13 18:25:09.352: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): verifySignature Sha256 for packageName=com.example.helloworldsample
12-13 18:25:09.352: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): verifyPayload for packageName=com.example.helloworldsample
12-13 18:25:09.352: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(3337): Signature checking.:<obscured>
12-13 18:25:09.362: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): num sigs = 1
12-13 18:25:09.362: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(3337): Fingerprint checking:<obscured>
12-13 18:25:09.362: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337):  num sigs = 1
12-13 18:25:09.362: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(3337): Fingerpirints checking:<obscured>
12-13 18:25:09.362: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): scopes has no mapping in json, returning null array
12-13 18:25:09.362: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): perm has no mapping in json, returning null array
12-13 18:25:09.362: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyServiceHelper(3337): Attempting to retrieve remote Android service. Ignore cached service=true


12-13 18:21:43.992: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyServiceHelper(3337): getAuthorizationServiceInstance
12-13 18:21:43.992: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyServiceHelper(3337): Number of services found : 0
12-13 18:21:43.992: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyServiceHelper(3337): Number of MAP services to compare = 0
12-13 18:21:43.992: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyServiceHelper(3337): Returning no service to use
12-13 18:21:44.012: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyAuthorizationHelper.PII(3337): Created UUID for request:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:44.012: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationHelper.PII(3337): Generating Redirect URI:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:44.022: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): num sigs = 1
12-13 18:21:44.022: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(3337): Fingerprint checking:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:44.022: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(3337): num sigs = 1
12-13 18:21:44.022: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(3337): Fingerprint checking:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:44.032: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationHelper.PII(3337): Generating OAUTH2 URL:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:44.032: I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.ThirdPartyAuthorizationHelper(3337): Starting External Browser
12-13 18:21:46.694: W/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationActivity(3337): onCreate
12-13 18:21:46.694: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationActivity.PII(3337): Received response from WebBroswer for OAuth2 flow:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:46.694: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationResponseParser.PII(3337): Received response from WebBroswer for OAuth2 flow:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:46.694: D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.AuthorizationResponseParser.PII(3337): Code extracted from response:<obscured>
12-13 18:21:46.694: E/AuthorizationListener(3337): inside error method
```

Can someone please help me in creating an App with AVS.